# Can not start monitor (android studio) on my Mac

Tags: android, monitor, ddms

1. I have Android studio installed on my Mac
2. Once navigate to `/Users/mac-194/Library/Android/sdk` and try to run Monitor, receive an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whTUR.png)

What can be done to make it work?

Comment: Please include your error message into the question as a text using [blocks of code format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/378063)

Comment: In this case especially the (latest) content of the log file referenced in the error message.

Comment: Error message is in the screen

Answer (score 0):

1. Install java-jdk 8 version under or equal 8-151
2. Go to monitor-x86_64 folder in mandoid-sdk
3. Right click on monitor.app and chose "Show Package Content"
4. Go to Contents folder and open Info.plist in any text editor
5. Find section "Eclipse" and uncomment line "-vm/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"
6. Correct this line with valid path to your eatly installed jdk. Save It.
7. Run monitor.app. Enjoy.